# Autofac won't resolve class from external dll

Tags: c#, dll, autofac

I'm trying to create an application that utilizes Autofac and loads external dlls. 
The following code works, if the DLL is located in the same folder and the program ran from the same folder:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies.ToArray()).
            Where(t => typeof(IImageConverter).IsAssignableFrom(t)).
            InstancePerLifetimeScope().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Now if I try to run the program from a different location but set the working directory as the directory where the DLL is located, autofac finds and loads the DLL, but doesn't resolve it to run it:

```
using (var scope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var processors = scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<IImageConverter>>();
    foreach (var process in processors)
        process.Process();
}
```

Those are the only autofac lines I have. The Interface is defined in a shared library and each module implements it by default. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what values are assigned `assemblies`.  Autofac will not load DLLs, it just scans the already loaded assemblies.

Read [Dynamicic Module Loading](http://devkimchi.com/631/dynamic-module-loading-with-autofac/) to determine how to load external DLLs.

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't really help. I did try doing that though. Hm.... I'll keep researching =). I'll up vote for the assistance =)